# Yii2 Class dektrium\user\Module does not exist

Tags: php, yii2

I have designed Yii2 powered blog by creating models, views and controllers but when I integrate user registration as explained in this tutorial https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-program-with-yii2-integrating-user-registration--cms-22974  I get:

> Class dektrium\user\Module does not exist

I fail to solve this error anyone who can direct me, please.

Comment: check if you have a file named Module.php in yourApp\vender\dektrium\yii2-user directory .. if not  you have not installed    correctly the estension  .. if you have updated  you question and add you config main.php file

Comment: When and where you get this error? You need to provide some code sample, error stack trace or something

Comment: I get this error when I run in the browser results to: Class dektrium\user\Module does not exist  in /home/ndulilo/FirstProject/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php. I have been following the tutorial linked above to integrate  with user registration.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to include the required module via composer:

```
"dektrium/yii2-user": "*"
```

Then run the "composer update" command in your console.

Answer (score 0):

Mabe you need to add to config:

```
    'user' => [
        'class' => 'dektrium\user\Module',
        'admins' => ['MegaAdmin'],
    ],
```

If you have it in common/config/main.php try to replace to backend/config/main.php